# Delphi XE5 Chart Special Range

Tags: delphi, charts, range, axis

I made a chart in Delphi XE5 and searched in its properties, but couldn't find what I want.
I want to assign special range to left axis of chart like ...,**-3,-2,1,2,3**,... , that are float numbers.

attention to I don't need -2 to 1 range but every number before -2 and after 1.

**x <= -2 and 1<=x**

Is it possible at all?

Thanks

Comment: could you elaborate? `automatic=false` with minimum and maximum are not what you are searching for?

Comment: And you can also set the increment if the default does not suit you